# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 user event email event type

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

When creating a script deployment, one of the possible event types is "Email". However, if I choose this even type and send an email (via the communication tab) no user events are triggered. Is it possible to trigger a user event script before an email is generated (beforeLoad)?

Comment: You can try deploying your script directly to the `Message` record instead.

Comment: Thanks, however, that doesn't seem to work. None of the user events trigger (even when event type is set to <blank>). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If there are reason that you don't just run your User Event script, with the email module, and send the necessary email from that script?  I may be missing what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: A 3rd party bundle is sending out emails - I when I saw the email event type I got my hopes up that a user event script could hook into the "before load" event as the email template is being populated. Would let you and easily calculate and pass along some custom field values that the template could use. Doesn't appear to be the case. Thanks for taking a look - I will find another approach.

Comment: You could try just adding another User Event script to run ahead of the one that is sending the emails.  If you know the fields that are being read for the email, you could alter them before the 3rd party script looks at them.  Not the best solution, but it may work... (BTW, this is one of the main reasons why I do not use 3rd party bundles, and/or locked scripts).

Comment: Ended up getting inconsistent results attempting to run a user event script prior to the bundle's logic. Only stable approach I found was to modify the bundle's workflow to execute a custom workflow script action prior to the email being sent. Not a great solution since I had to modify the bundle, but couldn't find any other work around.